# Parallel downloading of Bitmaps in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have two arraylists. Each one contains a few url. I want to download the bitmaps from these urls. My code now loos like this:

```
private class downloading extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, ArrayList<Bitmap>>    {

  @Override
  protected ArrayList<Bitmap> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {
        downloadBitmaps(params[0]);
        downloadBitmaps(params[1])
  }
```

This works fine. However I want to create a new thread in order to download the bitmaps of the second arraylist. But if do that I have to use to synchronized keyword in the downloadBitmaps method in order to avoid a ConcurrentModificationException. But if I do that the download process won't be faster. Can anyone propose me a safe and faster way to download the bitmaps?

Comment: where do you have ConcurrentModificationException? show downloadBitmaps and onPostExecute code. Do you place bitmaps to a collection? Then use it's Synchronized or Concurrent version. Or modify your storage from onPostExecute method.

Answer (score 1):

use / start the second AsyncTask for    downloadBitmaps(params[1])